# Cannot make getJson function to work

Tags: php, jquery, getjson

I have three separate files: a php webpage, a js script and a php webserver. a js script has to pass information from the website to the server.
The php file has a form with a submit button:

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1").submit(getfunction1);  
});    
</script>
<form id = "form1" method="GET"  action="search.php">
    <div class="form">
       <input type="text" id ="coursestex" value="course name"/>
       <input type="submit" id ="submitbut" value="submit"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

This is a js file that suppose to pass the information to the webserver.

```
function getfunction1(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.getJSON("exams.php", [{name: "course", value: "csc"}], function() {
        alert("correct");
    });
};
```

What is the problem here? I dont get the pop-up message so its not working right?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `$.getJSON` should be an object, not an array of objects.

```
$.getJSON("exams.php", {name: "course", value: "csc"}, function() {
    alert("correct");
});
```

In the PHP script you'll get these parameters with `$_GET['name']` and `$_GET['value']`. If it's supposed to be `$_GET['course'] == "csc"` then the object should be:

```
{ course: "csc" }
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but it is still not working(. In case of a successful getJSON function the pop-up windwos should appear, right? Everything after and before the getJSON function is working tho.